# Is there a way I can use something like a ? operator to check the value here and run either of these two without needing to use two if statements?

Tags: c#

I have this code and I would like to find a way to clean it up as much as possible. Would appreciate any suggestions people might have:

```
if (App.viewablePhrases.Count() == 1)
{
    await SetMessageAsync(
            msgType: "Practice",
            msg1: "Practice Mode",
            msg2: $"You have 1 card viewable out of {selCds} {msg}\n\nThe card in your deck has a total of {selPts} {ptsMsg1} {ptsMsg2}",
            btnText: App.cardsViewed ? "Continue Practice" : "Start Practice ");
    return true;
}

if (App.viewablePhrases.Count() > 1)
{
    await SetMessageAsync(
            msgType: "Practice",
            msg1: "Practice Mode",
            msg2: "You have " + App.viewablePhrases.Count() + " cards viewable out of a total of " + selCds + msg +
                  "\n\nThe cards in your deck have a total of " + selPts + ptsMsg1 + ptsMsg2,
            btnText: App.cardsViewed ? "Continue Practice" : "Start Practice ");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is `msg2` the only difference between the two? If so, you could have the condition set a variable with the correct value for `msg2` before making a call to `SetMessageAsync`.

Comment: Is the only difference between the two method calls is that one is `1 card` and the other is `x cards`?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Please put answers as answers

Comment: @DetectivePikachu it was a constructive comment...not an answer.

Comment: Complete code is an answer.

Comment: What if the count is Zero?

Comment: This really is a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both if conditions are just calling `SetMessageAsync()` method with `App.viewablePhrases.Count()`, just remove hard coded value `1` from string and use `App.viewablePhrases.Count()`.

```
if(App.viewablePhrases.Count() > 0)
{
    var cardString =  App.viewablePhrases.Count() == 1 ? "card" : "cards";
    await SetMessageAsync(
      msgType: "Practice",
      msg1: "Practice Mode",
      msg2: $"You have {App.viewablePhrases.Count()} {cardString} viewable out of {selCds} {msg}\n\nThe {cardString} in your deck has a total of {selPts} {ptsMsg1} {ptsMsg2}",
                        btnText: App.cardsViewed ? "Continue Practice" : "Start Practice ";
    return true;
}
```

No need of 2 if conditions

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Last update was typo error, but for first comment I fixed it, with ternary opearator

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar there we go :)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, You are superb. I was in hurry to answer. Initially, I did not pay attentions to each word of string. but thanks for helping me to improve my answer

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar you could take it a step further and get rid of the extra `cardString` var... but that will tend to get a little messy IMHO.

Comment: Do you mean to say ternary operation in string interpolation. I thought of it but it will  complicate the string as I need to use it in two different places.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar he did not mention it because his code implicitly takes care of this... Because his two if statements exclude the possibility of zero... So your code changed the functional aspect of the original code...

Comment: @Darkonekt, Completely agree and updated my answer accordingly. Line of code will execute if Count is greater than zero